# Python, How to use lxml XPath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

In python I had:

```
response = s.get(url, allow_redirects=False, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
reg_cart = soup.find('form', attrs={"name": "regCart"})
registered_courses = [i.a.text for i in reg_cart.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "course-number"})]
```

Now I want to replace `BeautifulSoup` with `lxml`, reading this:

https://timber.io/blog/an-intro-to-web-scraping-with-lxml-and-python/

I tried to implement what they used there and got:

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
registered_courses = doc.xpath('//div[@class="course-number"]/text()')
```

But for some reason my output is:

```
['\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t']
```

While previously it correctly showed courses numbers.

How can I fix this? plus how can I edit my path to return only those div tags under the form `regCart` and not in all response?

For example the html code looks something like:

```
        <form name="regCart" ....>
        </div><div class="entry-spacer"></div><div class="cart-entry">
                <div class="course-number">
                <a href="https://university.com/rishum/course/236756">236756</a>
            </div>
            <div class="course-name">
                מבוא למערכות לומדות              
            </div>
            <div class="course-points">
                3.0 נק'
            </div>
            <div class="entry-group">
                קבוצה 13
            </div>
```

Where I want to return `236756`

Comment: It will help a lot if you post part of the html, including at least one of the divs and surroudings. Preferably give it as a slice of the response.content (i am saying this because if you copy and paste from the browser it may not be exactly the same).

Comment: Try using `doc = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)` since `response.content` will display the content in bytes, whereas `response.text` will display it in unicode. -- And the website you're using, or a portion of the page you're interested in would be helpful as well.

Comment: @jsonV I tried but that didn't help fix the issue

Comment: I believe the issue is your relative xpath. It seems like it should be:
`registered_courses = doc.xpath('//div[@class="course-number"]/a/text()')`

Comment: @jsonV you are right I was trying .a instead of /a right now :)

Comment: Last thing, do you have any suggestion in which my code can be faster? even few milliseconds are important to me (plus I want low ram usage) for example is response.text faster than other etc...

Comment: Currently I have: `registered_courses = doc.xpath('//form[@name="regCart"]//div[@class="course-number"]/a/text()')`
    And: `in_cart_courses = doc.xpath('//form[@name="formSal"]//div[@class="course-number"]/a/text()')` Can I somehow do better here?

Comment: I imagine the use case is to register for courses at university. The requests/lxml libraries are pretty much as fast as it gets in Python. There's a few considerations, you'll have to experiment yourself to improve performance, but the largest bottleneck may just as well be your network latency (in ms) with requests.get()... whereas your other Python functions/code is working in the tens of microseconds.

Comment: @jsonV you are right, it's to register to courses as all students here wrote their own programs and free spots go within half a second... Is there better alternatives to requests.get?

Comment: Not that I know of. Perhaps someone else can chime in. Likely the best thing you can do is rent a couple of servers to run the same Python script -- this will improve your chances/decrease the spread between registration opening and your program making a request to the corresponding website at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your relative xpath: `//div[@class="course-number"]/text()`

```html
<div class="course-number">
  <a href="https://university.com/rishum/course/236756">236756</a>
</div>
```

This would grab the text field under the corresponding div; however, there is no text under the div. The text field of interest is actually inside the  tag, and the correct relative xpath is: `//div[@class="course-number"]/a/text()`